# Division between float and int won't compile

Tags: java, error-handling, int, double, division

First off, I'm still pretty new to Java so excuse me if the solution is something obvious.

I wrote code which is supposed to divide every second number in a specific range of numbers (from -5 to 20 in this example) with a float number but Java won't compile.

```
  public class exerciseD {
     static float Division (float r) {

      int n = (-5);
      float x = 0;

      if (n <= 20) {
       float x = n * r; 
       System.out.println(x);
       n = n + 2; 
      }
      else 
          return x;
  }
  public static void main(String[ ] args) {

      float y = Divison(22.5);
      System.out.println(y);

      }
  }
```

Error Message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method Divison(double) is undefined for the type exerciseD
at exerciseD.main(exerciseD.java:45)
```

What did I do wrong in this code? I just can't tell what the issue with double is. Every variable is either a float or int isn't it?

Thank you.

Comment: Check spelling: `division` and `divison` (missing `i`)

Comment: Youre right, thank you!

Comment: Floating-point literals default to double: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, You have Multiple errors the first one at if statement you are defining another X variable which is already defined above. 
the second error is the method name is **Division** and not **Divison**

The Third Error you cannot pass double to a float variable as parameter since 
you called `Division(22.5)` it should be **Division(22.5F)** to indicate that it's float otherwise it will pass it as double which will be **incompatible types possible lossy conversion from double to float**

the fourth error is you are missing the return statement of the Division method at if block

Comment: Thank you. I followed everything you suggested but I still get a error under "float y = Division(22.5);". Error Code: "The method Divison(float) is undefined for the type exerciseD"

What does that mean?

Comment: Yep the method name is missing (i) character please check the spelling